# Return the value of a date time key in a dictionary with datetime keys in python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like this -

```
{
        "2017-04-21T08:00:00-04:00": {
            "visibility": {
            "prevailing": 10.0,
            "units": "SM"
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 13.0,
            "crosswind": 2.0,
            "units": "KT"
        },
        "temperature": {
            "value": 13.9,
            "units": "C"
        },
        "sky": [
            {
                "cover": "clouds",
                "type": "broken",
                "height": 700.0,
                "units": "FT"
            }
        ],
        "code": "201704211056Z"
    },
    "2017-04-21T07:00:00-04:00": {
        "visibility": {
            "prevailing": 10.0,
            "units": "SM"
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 13.0,
            "crosswind": 2.0,
            "units": "KT"
        },
        "temperature": {
            "value": 13.9,
            "units": "C"
        },
        "sky": [
            {
                "type": "overcast",
                "height": 700.0,
                "units": "FT"
            }
        ],
        "code": "201704210956Z"
    }
    ...
}
```

After searching for a given datetime in the keys for the above dictinary, I need to return its value  which is also a dictionary of a weather report. I am getting a syntax error on the return statement. My code is -

```
tOff = takeoff.isoformat() #---> takeoff is the supplied datetime value to search for in the 
                                 dictionary

if tOff in weather.keys():
    return weather[tOff]. #---> I get a syntax error on this statement
else:
    #tm = datetime.takeoff.timetz()
    for t in weather.keys():
        if max(weather[t]) < tOff:
            return weather[t]
        else:
            return
```

Kindly help provide some guidance on why I get a syntax error and how to resolve it

Comment: what is the error message. can you share your Traceback error message or syntax error message please

Comment: You have a period at the end of the statement.  If you included the traceback it should be clear.

Comment: As an aside, https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode

Comment: first what is the `.` at the line `return weather[tOff].`? it seems like mistake, secondly - what is the meaning of `return` statement outside a function anyway? what have you tried to do at first place? lastly, if you may clear your request - I guess that dict comprehension will do your job

Comment: The extra period was the mistake. Thank you

Comment: @Cireo I did not have too much code. The code was only a few lines. The rest was all data. I don't think that the down vote by you was justified. For someone who is new to this community and just learning python, a little flexibility and tolerance would be nice

Comment: Downvotes aren't permanent =). Happy to remove it if you happen to clean it up.  By including all the irrelevant information first you cost 24 people a few minutes of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an additional . in this.

```
if tOff in weather.keys():
    return weather[tOff]. #---> I get a syntax error on this statement
```

You should remove the additional . see fixed code below

```
if tOff in weather.keys():
    return weather[tOff] #---> removed . from the return statement
```